# Prove the following inequality for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: integration, derivatives, summation, natural-numbers

Let $f(x)$ be a derivable function on the interval $(0,1)$ and continuous on $[0,1]$. 
Assume that $|f'(x)| \leq M$ for every $x \in (a,b)$. 
Prove the following inequality for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$
  \left| \int_0^1 f(x) dx - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) \right| \leq \frac{M}{n}.
$$

Comment: Is $(a,b) = (0,1)$?

Comment: i think yes, I have correctly transcribed the text of the exercise

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Do you intuitively see why this makes sense?

Comment: I solved it intuitively,but not mathematically.
I understood that if n tends to infinity:
$$
  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n f(k/n) 
$$
converges to
$$
 \frac{1}{1-0}\int_0^1 f(x) dx\
$$
but the inequality must hold for every n.
that's my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, we can get a slightly sharper bound.
Write

$$\int_0^1\,f(x)\,dx = \sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,f(x)\,dx$$

so then we need to estimate

\begin{align}
&\left| \sum_{k=1}^n\left[\left(\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,f(x)\,dx\right)-\frac1n f(k/n)\right]  \right|
\\=\,\,&
\left| \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,f(x) - f(k/n)\,dx\right)  \right|.
\end{align}

Now, use the mean value theorem.
For each $x\in\Big((k-1)/n,\, k/n\Big)$, there is some $\eta_x \in (x,\,k/n)$ with

$$f(x) - f(k/n) = f'(\eta_x) \big(x-k/n\big).$$

Then our estimate becomes

\begin{align}
&\left| \sum_{k=1}^n\left(\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,f(x) - f(k/n)\,dx\right)  \right|
\\\leqslant \,\,&
\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,|f'(\eta_x)| \big(k/n - x\big)\,dx
\\\leqslant \,\,&
M\,\sum_{k=1}^n\int_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}\,\big(k/n - x\big)\,dx
\\= \,\,&
M\,\sum_{k=1}^n\left[\frac{kx}n - \frac{x^2}2\right]_{(k-1)/n}^{k/n}
\\= \,\,&
M\,\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2n^2} = \frac M{2n}.
\end{align}

---

As a bonus, it's easy to verify that the bound is sharp when $f$ is affine (that is, when $f'$ is constant).